# Azure Storage: Table query filter works on Emulator but no on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

i'm trying to run a query on an Azure Storage table with this filter

```
(PartitionKey eq '6') and (ReservedOn ne datetime'0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z')
```

However, it works on my local emulator but not on Azure. would like to know what might be wrong with this query.

Thank you

Comment: `However, it works on my local emulator but not on Azure`. Is there any exception? or If there is some code demo will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is the date/time field. Minimum value of a date/time attribute supported in Azure is `12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.), UTC` (Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-the-table-service-data-model#tables-entities-and-properties - Please read `Property Types` section).

Since you're specifying a value smaller than this, I believe that is causing problems.